# Language switcher doesnt appear in Drupal

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, theming

I have enable the "locale" and "content translation" modules. Also I have two languages in my Drupal, Spanish and English, after that I have configured the detention method by URL.

I have finished my english page and I just need to translate the website to Spanish. When I set the language switcher to the website (the header or a columns) of my Structure I don´t see anything. I can click on "translate" button of the blocks of my web, I see the "Spanish" option, I click in "translate", but I get this message:

This string uses the Full HTML text format. Strings with this format are not allowed for translation.
Ok, I change the format to Plane Text but I loos of my HTML format, styles... I cant translate and I cant see the switcher to change to Spanish or English.

I would like to get a little of help because I tried a lot things this morning and I have not ideas right now.

Thanks.

Drupal versión 7.4 (the last one)

Comment: Did you put language switcher block in some (visible) ragion on Structure -> Blocks page?

Comment: Yes, I have the block in the header and I also check if appears in other region of my structure, but I get nothing.

Comment: How is your language detection configured ? Try to put it on `Path prefix with language fallback`

Comment: This !, I forgot this point, thanks =).